# Which option is selected among multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 radio buttons ,each radio button is having select tag and options in it as shown:

```html
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" id="b" value="Bus"> Bus
        <select id="select1" style='display:none;'>
        <option value="l3">Type :  </option>
        <option value="l1">AC Bus </option>
        <option value="l2">Non AC Bus </option>
        </select>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" id="f" value="Flight"> Flight
        <select id="select2" style='display:none;'>
        <option value="l3">Name :  </option>
        <option value="l1">Indian Airlines  </option>
        <option value="l2">Jet Airways  </option>
        </select>
```

I want to know which radio button and further which of its option is selected.How could I achieve this in script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Js, you can write as below,

```
var select1 = document.querySelector('#select1')
var select2 = document.querySelector('#select2')

select1.addEventListener('change', e => {
    console.log("select1 value", e.target.value)
})

select2.addEventListener('change', e => {
    console.log("select2 value", e.target.value)
})
```